# Can designs be placed under a wisteria trellis?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Can you display designs under a wisteria trellis? For example, I want to build one over a path I have (I'm using a brick design), but I don't know whether it will let me keep the path that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can place designs under the trellis in a sort of t shape--I have one and have done so.

If you have a 3x3 grid of space (which is how many tiles the trellis takes up), you can place the designs on the Xs while the Os represent the pillars of the trellis.

## OXO

## XXX

## OXO